# Singleton pattern interview

Tags: java, singleton

I am recently asked about java related question in an interview with following code, since I am very new to java and barely code in Java so I really have no idea what the following code does.

The question was 
    Select the option that describes the worst thing with the following code:

```
public class Bolton {
    private static Bolton INST = null;

    public static Bolton getInstance()
    {
        if ( INST == null )
        {
            INST = new Bolton();
        }
        return INST;
    }

    private Bolton() {
    }
}
```

Here are the options for this question

> 1. More than one instance of Bolton can be created
> 2. A Bolton will never be created
> 3. The constructor is private and can't be called
> 4. Value can be garbage collected, and the call to getInstance may return garbage data

Which of the above options is correct? And Why?

Comment: I'd go with 1.  Basically, there is no thread synchronization. This would allow the possibility for two or more threads to create more then one instance of the class.  I'd also suggest that it breaks the Java Naming conventions, but that's not an option.

Comment: Technically, 2 is correct also.  From this code alone, a `Bolton` will never be created (getInstance() is not actually invoked). :)

Comment: @JakeStoeffler I like the way you think, I'm going to add that to our interview questions ;)

Comment: Well I stand corrected, sync issues didn't actually occur to me... Time go rewrite my singleton!

Comment: @Thihara Welcome to my world :P

Comment: @Thihara make sure to avoid double-checked locking!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

The idea of a Singleton Pattern is to only have one available instance of a class. Therefore the `constructor` is set to `private` and the class maintains, in this case, a `getInstance()` method that either calls an existing instance variable, `INST` in this class, or creates a new one for the executing program. The answer is probably 1, because it's not thread safe. It may be confused for 3, which I had put down earlier, but that is by design, technically, so not actually a flaw.

Here's an example of **Lazy Initialization**, thread-safe singleton pattern from Wikipedia:

```
public class SingletonDemo {

    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {  } 

    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonDemo.class){
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new SingletonDemo();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Setting the instance variable to [`volatile`](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) tells Java to read it from memory and to not set it in cache.

[Synchronized statements or methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) help with [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)).

Read more about [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) which is what happens for a "lazy initialization" singleton

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. I chose 3 when it was asked. It was a wild guess as I mentioned I know very less about Java. :(. But this will help me in the future or I may start my hands get dirty with Java too. :)

Comment: How about option 2? Based on @JakeStoeffler comment.

Comment: A `Bolton` will be created, but only as an instance variable. And I think he's referring to the fact that there is no `main()` method created to invoke it.

Comment: -1 for [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: @Christopher seems a typo in your code - you mistakenly included that `getInstance` method inside constructor body

Comment: +1 for double-checked locking done right, but perhaps you could write it as `SingletonDemo result = instance; if (result==null) {...} return result;` (Bloch says it is faster, because the volatile variable is only read once).

Comment: @Bingo thanks for the edit, must have missed when I was typing. (I don't know why I didn't copy and paste..)

Answer (score 2):

Interviewer basically wants to check your knoweldge of Singleton pattern . Can the pattern be broken?. Ans is Yes. Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-2001/jw-0112-singleton.html) or google - when singleton is not a singleton.

Best course is to use [Enum based Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) as suggested by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 2):

> More than one instance of Bolton can be created

This option is correct due to lack of synchronization in the above code.

Suppose two threads concurrently check for `null` and both will find that the value is `null` and both will call the constructor **(which refutes singleton)**.

Also there is other catch in this, even if two threads dont check for `null` together but suppose one thread calls the constructor; but the constructor wont return till the object is constructed (assuming that the object is costly to create and requires time), so till the constructor returns some other thread might check for the `null` condition and still find the object as `null` as the object is *not yet constructed.*

This scenario in which some pre condition is called *check-then-act* which is culprit for Race.

For singleton there are two standards that are being used:

- [Double Checked locking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html)
- [Enum based singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697726/how-to-initialize-java-enum-based-singleton)

**UPDATE:**
Here is another great article which discusses the [double checked locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Comment: Actually Bloch says that the double-check **is the technique of choice**, but the variable must be declared `volatile` (because there is no lock if the instance is already initialized).

Comment: Of course, I will revert to +1 once you fix that :), your answer is quite comprehensive.

Comment: @Javier I have edited that. My bad. Also I read somewhere that even if we do double locking it is not serialization safe. For that enum pattern should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The `getInstance()` method should be synchronized, otherwise many instances could be created if multiple threads calls `getInstance()` at the same time. So I would select option 1.

Answer (score 1):

We use Singleton Pattern when we want to have only one object of this class and it will be used every where. So to restrict the class to create many objects, we should use  `private` for constructor of this class. And create one `public` function to return the object of this class.

```
public class MethodWin {
    private int isLoggedOn=0;
    private static MethodWin objectMethodWin = new MethodWin();
    private MethodWin() { }
    public static MethodWin getInstance() {
        return objectMethodWin;
    }
    public void setIsLoggedOn(int value) {
       this.isLoggedOn=value;
    }
    public int getIsLoggedOn() {
       return this.isLoggedOn;
    }
}
```

So when we need to create this obect, we should:

```
MethodWin meth = MethodWin.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Original Answer is that only one instance of Bolton is created.

Answer (score 0):

Through reflection we can create many objects even if the constructor is private. 
In multi-threaded environment there are chances to create more than one instance. 
Through serialization there are chances to create more than one object.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is `2) A Bolton will never be created` because when you create instance the constructor will call inside constructor initialization when call getInstance method then answer will be single instance will be created.